# Simple web site user management with Spring

Tags: spring, web-applications, user-management

I've done many sites, using Java, Php, etc... When I needed user management I would use HttpSession and a DB to keep passwords and eventually session data.

What's the recomended/standard way of doing this with Spring in a simple way?

Comment: What do you meant by user management? To manage users you do not need session... You are probably asking about authorization in web apps?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "sub"-project of Spring: [Spring-Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/). That is exactly what you need. It provides also a "jdbc-user-service" authentication provider which reads the user  from a database table out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security is great when the developer wants to secure his web app. But what about creating the account? and "forgot password"?

Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562266/create-account-forgot-password-and-change-password).

> "I have implemented a JAVA project for this use case. It is open
>   source, based on Spring-Security. A release version is on
>   Maven-Central, so you do not need to compile it, but instead you can
>   fetch it as maven-dependency to your project!"

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.ohadr</groupId>
     <artifactId>authentication-flows</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.0-RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```